# Angular: can't set contents of mock HTTP response

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking

I have this code:

```
  /**
   * Attempt login with provided credentials
   * @returns {Observable<number>} the status code of HTTP response
   */
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<number> {
    let body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.append('grant_type', 'password');
    body.append('username', username);
    body.append('password', password);

    let connObservable = this.http.post(Constants.LOGIN_URL, body, null)
      .map(res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
          log(res.json());
        }
        return res.status;
      })
      .catch(err => { return Observable.throw(err.status) })
      .publish();

    // this ensures that side effects will be present regardless os whether
    // the client subscribes to the returned Observable
    connObservable.connect();

    // no need for the client to know that we use ConnectableObservable internally
    return connObservable as Observable<number>;
  }
```

And I want to unit test it using this code:

```
describe('AuthenticationService', () => {

  let sut: AuthenticationService;
  let authTokeServiceStub: AuthTokenServiceStub;
  let mockBackend: MockBackend;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpModule ],
      providers: [
        AuthenticationService,
        {provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend},
        {provide: AuthTokenService, useClass: AuthTokenServiceStub}
      ]
    });

    sut = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);
    authTokeServiceStub = TestBed.get(AuthTokenService);
    mockBackend = TestBed.get(XHRBackend);
  });


  describe('login()', () => {

    it('should store retrieved access token on successful response', () => {
      mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
        let options = new ResponseOptions();
        options.body = JSON.stringify({access_token : 'accessToken'});
        options.status = 200;
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(options));
      });
      spyOn(authTokeServiceStub, 'setAuthToken');
      sut.login('username', 'password');
      expect(authTokeServiceStub.setAuthToken).toHaveBeenCalledWith('accessToken');
    });

  });

});
```

The problem is that `log(res.json())` always produces empty object: `{}`.

In order to isolate the problem I tried to change mock response's status to 400, but it did not have any effect. Looks like `options` argument to `Response` object is being ignored.

I tried to wrap the test in `async` and then in `fakeAsync` and add `tick()` and `tick(50)` between stages, but it did not work either.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the `@Component` annotation of the `AuthenticationService`? Also the `@NgModule` it is declared at?

Comment: Can you try calling `tick();` (`import {tick} from '@angular/core/testing';`) somewhere after the `mockBackend...subscribe()` line?

Comment: @acdcjunior, I have already tried to add `async` and `fakeAsync` with `tick` in different places. Still not working. Furthermore, it looks like the response is sent and everything is alright from scheduling perspective. It is just that the response is always an empty response with 200 status code, regardless of how it is constructed...

Comment: If you change the `option.status`, does it reflect in the sut?

Comment: @acdcjunior nope

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your response to

```
new Response(new ResponseOptions(response))
```